# How to fix "Error: spawn cmd ENOENT" while installing create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am installing a create-react-app. 
I have already managed to do it few weeks ago, but this time it doesn't work. It throws an error when I do the command 'npm start'.

I followed the tutorial on reactjs.org.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled latest version of nodejs (v10.15.3). My version of npm is : 6.9.0.

Any clue to help to solve this issue? Thanks

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! memory@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the memory@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Amelie\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-07T12_02_27_185Z-debug.log

C:\Users\Amelie\Documents\Formation Développeur WEB\React OCR\memory>.\node_modules.bin\eslint
Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable.

C:\Users\Amelie\Documents\Formation Développeur WEB\React OCR\memory>
```

Comment: what's your OS?

Comment: Windows 10
I solved the problem using this tutorial https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffacebook%2Fcreate-react-app%2Fissues%2F6908&h=AT0qQitTXmdnNde7fYJO7LRCudCF-eMp885ezEahX01Rin_QunmYGWcodW0sn-4ZOk7T53XQOs0CT-j95S-20sGnnXy8QelO-csMthqAjN6mdIoUwSpkTJU_hAyTPoQBVsNSyRzldoW3AZ-PitD3Flfl4_Uz6m4L
Thanks !

Comment: @amelie help paste this solution here, I can not login workplace

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6908

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading your react-scripts dependency to `^2.1.8` in your package.json file.

It worked for me